# Access the event object from global event bus in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have some pages (in Laravel) that each includes a form with different action URI's:

```
<form method="post" action="/route1">
    ...
    <button @click="emitEvent('event1')">
</form>
```

In Vuejs root I have only a method that calls the event globally:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    methods: {
        emitEvent(event, payload) {
            EventBus.$emit(event, payload);
        }
    }
});
```

In my Component I have a listener for the global event:

```
data() {
    return {
        someKey: false //this value is dynamic
    }
}
mounted() {
    EventBus.$on('event1', (event) => {
        console.log(event); //returns undefined
        if(this.someKey) {
             window.location = "/another-url"; 
             //Go to this url ONLY if the is true, else go to the url from the action attibute of the form
        }
    });
}
```

So basically, if a certain condition is meet in vue, I want to load that page.

Right now, the page will load the url from html form even if the condition in vuejs is meet or not.

I tried @click.prevent="emitEvent('event1')" instead of @click but in this way, if the condition is false and the window.location doesn't run, it gets stuck.

I am thinking to access the event object and then manually preventDefault() but only if necesary, so if that's not the case, the page will load the url from the form's action, but I can't find a way to get that event object inside Vue.

I found that the event name is in EventBus._events.event1 but I can't go forward because there are only empty properties and I`m not sure haw can I access the default event so I can prevent it.

I`m sure there it must be a easier/shorter and better way then giving an id/class to each form, then access it, then get its action attribute which is the url I need and finally if access that url if the condition is not meet. This way it may work, but it's an old style maybe?

Anyway, I am stack here and I appreciate any help.

Comment: how about moving the click event to form submit event and then return false to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in the `@click`-listener, your call:

```
emitEvent('event1')
```

calls the function with ONE param, therefore your `event`-param in your function will always be 'event1' of type 'string'.

To answer your question you would have to change your @click-listener to:

```
@click="(e) => { emitEvent(e, 'event1') }"
```

Explanation:

When the @click-listener gets a `function` as value it will call the function with the `event` as the first (and only) param. In your case you give the @click-listener an `undefined` as you dont have a return-value.

Here take a closer look at [this doc.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers)

Comment: Yes, you are right. That was the missing piece. First I had an error using your code, then I found that the parameters must be reversed because the first one gets sent as the event name and the second one (the event) is actually the payload. But anyway, yes you are right, and now the event.preventDefault() works and the page redirects if the condition is meet. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would go this way (as usual):

```
<form method="post" action="/route1" @submit="emitEvent('event1')">
    ...
    <button type="submit">
</form>
```

This way, the submit event will obey the preventions. And then:

```
var that = this; // added a buffer to use in the event (hackish)
EventBus.$on('event1', (event) => {
    if(that.someKey) {
         window.location = "/another-url";     
         return false; // will prevent submission and change the url
    }
    return true; // will proceed submission
});
```

Comment: I just tried, but it loads the same url from the form.

Comment: Then you might not be accessing `someKey`. I'll update my answer now.

Comment: still no success. Anyway, as I said, I have many pages like that (which includes the form) and I would like to avoid a solution to edit the html on each one, and instead I would like to work on the js side if it's possible.

Comment: Ok then preventing the form submit with the click event seems very hard, maybe impossible.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but I think there must be a way to access that event. I saw it in EventBus._events.event1 .. and some other nested arrays which ends like [[Scopes]], but I can't access it using .(dot) notation ... not sure why. Anyway, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Did you try returning false to the click event? What happens if you use the modified event of mine with your click function? And you may be accessing the event with `this.$event` variable.